# Auto save data with Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, web-applications

Right now I'm building a team based project with Node.js/MySQL/React and have been stuck at a ToDo list part. I would like to know what is the recommended or fastest way how to save data or options to database automatically and without any submit button on each row.

[Todo item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHLBk.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could do a single `POST` when adding a new row, and whenever you change the options you could do a `PUT` request, but as a general design rule I'd advise against it : you want to be able to review all your changes before committing them to the database, plus this requires a lot more requests, hence more controllers rather than just having one.

Looking at your screenshot why don't you have a single submit button at the bottom of the table ?

Comment: I have only one submit button for adding new item, but my idea is to let user to edit that specific item row without some button. I think it's more faster and intuitive.